# Node is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(Node<E>) in Comparable where E is type variable

Tags: java, generics, abstract, comparable, compareto

I am trying to implement the compareTo method to my code since I want to create a method to compare generics, but I cannot since I'm getting an override error when implementing Comparable. Please let me know how I can fix this error.

```
 protected static class Node<E> implements Position<E>, Comparable<Node<E>>
    {
        private E element;
        private Node<E> parent;
        private Node<E> left;
        private Node<E> right;
        
        public Node(E e, Node<E> parent, Node<E> left, Node<E> right)
        {
            this.element = e;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }
        public boolean find(Node<E> root, Node<E> key) {
            while(root != null){
                if(key.compareTo(root.getParent())>0){
                    root=root.getRight();
                }
                else if(key.compareTo(root.getParent())<0){
                    root=root.getLeft();
                }
                else
                    return true;
            }
            return false;

    }


    }
```

I deleted most of the methods in the class, since it wasn't letting me submit so much code without saying much.

Comment: Where is your compareTo function body?

Comment: @igor_bal Hi igor, I added the method back with the compareTo method

Comment: You need to override compareTo method by yourself, so you should write 
```@Override public int compareTo (Node<E>) { //your code} ``` in your Node<E> class

Comment: @igor_bal So I would put my boolean method into   Override public int compareTo (Node<E>) { //your code}  ?

Comment: No, but now Java doesn't know how to compare Node<E>, that's why you need to tell it by writing your own compareTo method